# Looping through associated Lists in a class?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that has several `List<T>` objects in it.  These Lists are "associated" so that the first items in each are related, and the second ones, and so on (kind of like fields within a single record).  I want to loop through the Lists together to alter some of the data simultaneously per "record".

With a `foreach` loop, I can loop through one List without tracking the record via `i` or some such.  However, I don't know how to simultaneously access the related items in the other Lists.  Do I have to count it out using a variable like `i`, or is there a better way?  I'm still pretty new to generics and class-based programming.  Am I totally missing a better way to arrange this data?

Answer (score 2):

So this is kind of a fun problem... Note that I suspect some different data modeling might have been able to get around this issue, but if you stored the related items together in a Tuple you could get away from having sync'ed lists... It seems very dangerous to have these sync'ed lists and rely on the fact that they *should* all correspond at "i" in that any sorting, grouping, or paging (Skip/Take) could break this paradigm.

If you stored them in a `List<Tuple<ItemTypeFromList1, ItemTypeFromList2, ... ItemTypeFromListN>>` then you could keep the items together in a single list such that you could do a single iteration over the list and then just act on the N items in the tuple appropriately

Comment: I agree. Even better would be to come up with a domain object instead of the tuple, if the OP has something like that in his model.

Comment: Never heard of domain objects, but have heard of Tuples (though never used them).  Looking them up seems to say that they are immutable once created.  Does that mean if I create a `List<Tuple>` and assign a set of values, they are locked?  Because that won't work for me, since I need to change the data later on.  In that case, would this work better as `List<Class>` then?

Comment: @techturtle You cannot reassign a tuples properties. So a class would be better in this case.

Comment: MAV, great point! and @techturtle, aquaraga just meant "class"... A domain object isn't a specific strongly-typed object, it's simply the objects that constitute your domain or your context... If you're writing an insurance app, your domain is insurance... if you're writing a storefront, you're likely going to have some version of an ecommerce domain...

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard for loop and an index (your i) that will allow you to access the same element in each array.  There is no better way to do it.

Comment: I disagree... Your way is one way, but it's fragile... If anyone ever returns a sorted or paged list then the method falls apart... And what's worst is it may not be obvious... You wouldn't know that your data was getting mis-associated until you began exposing bad data...

Comment: I too don't think this is always the best way to go. The fact that the OP has to slice through the lists simultaneously is a smell in the modelling.

Comment: @Rikon, aquaraga I agree it isn't the best model to try to keep three lists in sync.  However, given the setup provided in the question, three lists, then the basic for loop is the way to iterate through them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of would be to use a standard for-loop. When the index is important I always prefer for-loops instead of foreach.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++)
{
      list1[i].someMethod();
      list2[i].someMethod();
      ...
}
```

I assume all lists are of equal length when they are related as you say.

You might want to look into grouping the related items together in a single class and then have only one list, instead of multiple.

Answer (score 1):

How about collecting all data for the 'row' in a single class and place instances of this class in a single list as opposed to multiple lists you are trying to keep in synch

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code

```
foreach (var i in firstList )
        {
            var s1 = secondList[firstList.LastIndexOf(i)];
            var s2 = thirdList[firstList.LastIndexOf(i)];
        }
```

Hope this is the answer you want..:)